Unable to browse to company website on domain joined machine
I support a client with a very simple network. They have an Active Directory domain called such as corp.example.com. Their public facing website is example.com.
Any domain joined computer cannot visit example.com for some reason.
However, when I am using a non-domain joined machine on the same internal LAN, I can visit the site just fine. I immediately thought the issue was DNS related but I can't seem to find where the problem could be.
All the internal domain zones and such are corp.example.com not example.com.
When I ping example.com from a domain joined machine, it does resolve to the correct IP of the website.

I see a problem when I use nslookup.
C:\Users\administrator\nslookup company.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.16
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    company.com.company.com
Address:  66.123.56.71
You can see that the non-authoritative answer seems to duplicate the domain name. When I run this same nslookup on a non-domain joined machine, it does not duplicate the domain.

When I run Wireshark and apply a filter for the IP address of the public company website, I get a lot of destination unreachable but I know the site is up and running.

Use dig (install wsl, dig in cygwin or whatever) and run dig example.com @<ip of domain nameserver>.

It sounds like there isn't a DNS suffix search order configured, and the endpoint is defaulting to using DNS devolution and appending the root domain.
